# Architectural issues of using smart contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapps, architecture, besu

As part of my master's thesis MVP, I am developing a project on the implementation of an accounting system for electronic document management using smart contracts.

Now there is a question of architecture. Namely, as far as I understand, at the current iteration of blockchain development, smart contract technology, it is difficult to implement a decentralized application with only the capabilities of smart contracts as a server and a single point for organizing all business processes. That is, the limitations of data structures, the speed of reading data from the blockchain does not allow the system to be implemented fast enough.

**Subject area for the application**: supply chains of goods.

**The entities in smart contracts** will be as follows:

- User: personal data, ID in the system, address, inventory (ID of the goods that the user currently owns)
- Product: has data characterizing the product, product history (movement and condition, owners (links to addresses or user IDs))
- Order (typical for legal entities: distributors, manufacturers, carriers): Confirmations from the parties to the agreement (transfer agreement), an array of product IDs (each product with an ID can be marked as transferred or not transferred, if during a real exchange of goods with the specified ID was), confirmation of the parties on the consent to the execution of the order

From here, thoughts appeared: to implement a hybrid architecture, where there will be an intermediate server with a database (as part of the MVP I will use supabase), where you can quickly aggregate data, read it, and the like.

The blockchain itself and smart contracts, in this case, will perform what functions?! Storing permanently committed transactions to reflect their fact, which makes it impossible to change the data. That is, the blockchain will, as it were, insure business processes from interference in them after the transaction is completed.

The blockchain itself in my case also needs a hybrid type. Hyperledger Fabric with its access by permissions is not suitable because:

- The system (smart contract) assumes the use of roles with different levels of access to use the functions in the smart contract
- (buyers) should also have access to the system (namely, to the blockchain) and mainly read data about the supply chain, for example, which way the product went to the client, the list of counterparties through whom the product passed, and any other data
- it is possible to fill in some personal information about your account, which may be relevant for customers who were registered in the system by managers who sold the goods
- only authorized users (approved by the administrator??) can have access to the deployment of new contracts and new blockchain nodes. This point is the most confusing, because the blockchain must also have the capabilities of public blockchains.
- the very concept of cryptocurrency is not supposed to be used, that is, only the accounting function of the blockchain is of interest

Found options for implementing this kind of hybrid blockchains:

- hyperledger sawtooth
- hyperledger besu

**In summary, the following questions**:

- is it possible to implement such a system in principle, that access to a smart contract and operations in them can be from ordinary people who connected to the blockchain network and created an account there using metamask
- which blockchain platform should I use
- since solidity has many limitations in the development of smart contracts, does it make sense to pay attention to the implementation of a smart contract in the javascript language (it is easier to work with complex data structures there) and maybe then you can completely abandon the intermediate server, the purpose of which is simply in convenient providing data
- maybe you could suggest something else

Please, please help me with advice.